# strange issue, magento site can only be visited by using https url

Tags: magento, redirect, https

I'm trying to set up a magento store(let's call it site A) for my friend's little shop, he has another web shop (let's call it site B) running on the server at the moment.

I've installed magento(ver 1.7.0.2) in the `/magento` folder, my first issue is the store can't be visited by using normal `http://` url, it can only be visited by using `https://` url.

For example: if I type `myfriendsshop.com/magento` or into the browser, I will be redirected to myfriendsshop.com which is the homepage of site B,

if I type `myfriendsshop.com/magento/index.php` into the browser instead, I will be able to visit the homepage of site A.

If I put `https://kmsdirect.co.uk/magento/` into the browser, I will also be able to visit the homepage of site A.

I've also created some test products in site A, but if I clicked on the product I will be redirect to site B again, unless I use `https://` url to visit that product page.
Anyone know what caused this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to check on these two things:

- Are your vhosts set up correctly for Site A and Site B?
- Check your base-url's in the backend under System - Configuration - General - Web. Make sure they're configured properly for both Site A and Site B